# C# - Copy a file to user folder

Tags: c#

I'm making the GUI program that users can decompile/recompile an APK file but compiling won't work correctly becuase the framework file is missing. I'm making the simple framework installer that must be installed on user folder (for apktool.jar). Instead using the path that only works on my computer. i want to make it work for all users.

here is the code i made

```
File.Copy(@"do-not-touch\1.apk", @"C:\Users\quoc\apktool\framework\1.apk");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Enumeration to get the path like so:

```
var userDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Note: Please use `ApplicationData` and not the root profile, it's rude to fill the user's toplevel profile with stuff.

Comment: Note, it is also rude to fill a user's `ApplicationData` without first making a subfolder for your program too, so `userDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "apktool")` would be the "root" you put all the new files and folders in.

Comment: True, but the OP has subfolders below the profile dir. I assumed those would be retained after the root location was determined.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to make it more clear so he did not try to do `Path.Combine(userDir, "1.apk")` using the original code example.

Comment: but how can i get the program to create a folder if it does not exist?